# Creating an AutoFixture specimen builder for a type

Tags: c#, autofixture

I'm creating an AutoFixture specimen builder for a particular type, in this case `System.Data.DataSet`. The builder will return a `FakeDataSet`, which is a customized `DataSet` for testing.

The following doesn't work, with `dataSet` always returning null, even when a `DataSet` is being requested (I can tell by drilling into the `request` properties).

```
public class DataSetBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var dataSet = request as DataSet;
        if (dataSet == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        return new FakeDataSet();
    }
}
```

This variation does work, but seems overly complex. It feels like there is a better way to accomplish the same thing, and I'm just missing something.

```
public class DataSetBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var seededRequest = request as SeededRequest;
        if (seededRequest == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        var requestType = seededRequest.Request as Type;
        if (requestType == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        if (requestType.Name != "DataSet")
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        return new FakeDataSet();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It would be simpler to do this:

```
fixture.Register<DataSet>(() => new FakeDataSet());
```

but if you *want* to use a SpecimenBuilder, this should also work:

```
public class DataSetBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var t = request as Type;
        if (typeof(DataSet).Equals(t))
            return new FakeDataSet();

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd use the first option.

Comment: I agree, using Register is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question: I cannot do var t = request as Type; because it always returns null. It is always of type SeededRequest. Why?

Comment: @AdanayMartín If it _always_ returns `null` then it sounds like something isn't right. A repro (in a new question) is required if I should have even a chance of answering.